# VBScript InnerHtml - Firing too early

Tags: dom, vbscript, innerhtml

So when running some code, along the lines of:

```
document.getElementById("getForge").style.display = "inline" ' this is hidden by default, show it.
DoStuffHere()
document.getElementById("getForge").style.display = "none" ' hide it again after DoStuffHere().
```

So I can show a popup and then hide it again when the function is done, the code seems to be actionned in the DOM before the function has completed its work (a download).

I was under the belief that VBScript would be carried out line by line until it reached that last style change, this has proven not to be the case, is there any way around this?

All I am trying to do is get a div to show until the process is complete and then hide it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code is MC ND's solution to the issue, I have simply changed around some of the variables and names involved.

The setTimeout function did have a parenthesis issue however that is corrected in the below code.

```
Function DoAlert
    Dim alert
    Set alert = document.getElementById("divForge")

    If alert.style.display = "inline" Then 
        Call GetForge()
        alert.style.display = "none"
    Else
        alert.style.display = "inline"
        setTimeout GetRef("DoAlert"), 50
    End If 

End Function
```

Thank you very much for your help MC ND, very informative.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not firing too early. And yes, your beliefs on VBScript execution are correct. But script execution and element rendering are not concurrent processes. Any change to the DOM will not be updated while the code is still running. You need to end code execution, return control to the browser to do the updates and then continue with the execution of the code.

So, in your code, the display property is changed to `inline` but not rendered (code still running), the function is called and then the change to the display property is reverted.

You can solve it with something like (just from memory, not tested)

```
Function DoStuffHandler
    Dim popup
    Set popup = document.getElementById("getForge")

    If popup.style.display = "inline" Then 
        Call DoStuffHere()
        popup.style.display = "none"
    Else
        popup.style.display = "inline"
        Call setTimeout( GetRef("DoStuffHandler"), 50 )
    End If 

End Function
```

The code, using the `display` property of the popup as a switch will:

- If the popup is visible, then execute the main function and when done change the display and leave to let the browser update the DOM
- If the popup is not visible then change the display property, prepare a callback to this same function and leave to let the browser update the DOM. After 50 milliseconds the browser will call the indicated function.

Comment: Haven't tested this yet, but I guess that would work in a general sense by replacing getForge with a variable without quotes? I currently call the function by link with an onclick.

Comment: @Bolte, from the `getElementById`point of view there is no difference from a string and a variable containing a string.

Comment: Would that code not cause the DoStuffHere() function to be repeated every 50 miliseconds when the popup is not visible? Not quite getting that else routine, looks like it is basically going to, if display is not inline, change it to inline. So that to me makes me think it will always be visible.. How does that part work?

Comment: @Bolte, no, the `setTimeout` will call the function after the indicated time only once. To get the function called every x milliseconds, you need to use `setInterval`. And, you can see in the code that in the second call to the function (from `setTimeout`) the `display` property is changed to `none`.

Comment: Ok, so outside of this do I have to both set the div inline first and call the DoStuffHandler for this to work?

Comment: @Bolte, no. The code assumes that the display is not `inline`. The `false` part of the `if` will set the display to `inline`, set the callback and leave code execution to let the brower update the DOM. The callback will be called by the browser and now, with the display set to `inline` the `true` part of the `if` will execute the main routine and change the display property to `none`

Comment: Ahh yes, I get it now, so I simple just need to use my preferred method: `<a href="#" onclick="vbscript:DoStuffHandler()">Test</a>` and the function will do the rest, right?

Comment: This line: `setTimeout( GetRef("GetForge"), 50 )` produces a `Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub Error 800A0414`, I have tried removing them and changing the syntax around but it still produces this error. What am I doing wrong here? Just to clarify, the function that does the downloading etc is GetForge, I have changed the DIV ID to something else.

Comment: Scratch that, me being an idiot, I obsfuciate my functions into a dll file, and to run it to check code, I rename to VBS, made a schoolboy error ha. All sorted now!